# Slice out of bounds using [][]int but works with map[int][]int

Tags: go, go-map

Why does this code work

```
graph := make(map[int][]int, 0)

graph[0] = append(graph[0], 1)
```

But if you replace first line with `graph := make([][]int, 0)` I get `panic: runtime error: index out of range`? It's very weird.

Comment: Because the length of slice is 0 so you cannot append to it

Comment: @Himanshu isn't the purpose of append to dynamically change size of slice? i tried graph := [][]int{} and that doesn't work either.

Comment: yes it does but you have to set its key first since its two dimension slice that's why the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do make in `graph := make(map[int][]int, 0)`, you are allocating memory to your map, not to array. So you might do this only 
`graph := make(map[int][]int)`.

Decomping you code:

```
type a []int
type m map[int]a

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    //decomping graph := make(map[int][]int, 0)
    graph := make(m)

    //map is empty
    fmt.Println(len(graph))

    //decomping graph[0] := append(graph[0], 1)
    itm_a := 1
    arr_a := []int{}

    //appeding item to "a" type
    arr_a = append(arr_a, itm_a)

    //appending array of a to graph
    graph[0] = arr_a

    //print graph
    fmt.Println(graph)
}
```

See in [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/BmMeM-2t0Xh).

The error that you are getting is caused for conceptual error. 
When you does `graph := make([][]int, 0)`, you are allocation memory to a slice of slice, not an array. See in https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals.

So you can does this (decomping solution):

```
type a []int
type m []a

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    //decomping graph := make([][]int, 0)
    //see that you must be set the length
    graph := make(m, 0)

    //map is empty
    fmt.Println(len(graph))

    //this is incorrect: graph[0] := append(graph[0], 1)
    //this is correct:   graph[0] := append(graph[0], []int{1})
    //see:
    itm_a := 1
    arr_a := []int{}

    //appeding item to "a" type
    arr_a = append(arr_a, itm_a)

    //appending slice of a to graph (slice)
    graph = append(graph, arr_a)

    //print graph
    fmt.Println(graph)
}
```

See in [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wtSGKzwwEPL)

Answer (score 6):

Lets simplify your code, to make it more obvious what's happening ([Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/M85Qo8lW_0N)):

```
graph1 := make(map[int]int, 0)
graph2 := make([]int, 0)

x := graph1[0] // Success
y := graph2[0] // Panic
```

From this we see that the difference is due to `map[int]` vs `[]int` -- the second array in your type is actually irrelevant.

Now to understand why this is happening, we need to understand how Go handles map and slice access.  From [Go Maps in Action](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action) we learn:

> If the requested key doesn't exist, we get the value type's *zero value*.

In your original code, the zero value for a slice (`[]int`), is `nil`, and `append()` treats `nil` as the first argument as an empty slice.

But when we try to access the *0th* element of an empty slice, we get a panic, because the slice is empty.

In summary, `append` and the second slice of your type are both red herrings in your question. The panic happens when trying to access the non-existent element in the first dimension of your slice.

Answer (score 2):

The code panics due to slice length being `0`. If you want to append anything to the slice, you just have to provide its length as below.

```
graph := make([][]int, 1)
fmt.Println(len(graph))
graph[0] = append(graph[0], 1)
fmt.Println(graph)
```

To append data to a slice at first level, append to its first index and then append to second level just like below.

```
graph := make([][]int, 0)
fmt.Println(len(graph))
graph = append(graph, []int{1})
```

Check [Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/Uzt77tFl_Eq)

Answer (score 1):

`make(map[int][]int, 0)` creates a `map` of `[]int`.

By design in Go you can get any element from a map. And if it doesn't exist you receive the "zero" value which here is an empty slice.

```
graph := make(map[int][]int)

graph[4] = append(graph[4], 1)
graph[7] = append([]int{}, 1, 2)
graph[11] = append([]int{1, 2, 3}, 4, 5)
```

printing it gives this slice:

```
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", graph)

map[int][]int{
    4:[]int{1},
    7:[]int{1, 2},
    11:[]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
}
```

Your second example create an empty slice of `[]int` slices. Slices work differently from maps, so indexing an element that doesn't exist will give you a panic.